# Displaying multiple hierarchy levels in an MDX query

Tags: mdx, olap

I'm trying to get the following data from a TFS OLAP cube in a single query

```
[Work Item].[System_ID] | [Work Item].[System_Title] | [Measures].[BaselineWork]
13426                   | Do some work               | 5
```

Sounds pretty simple huh? That's what I thought too, but having 0 knowledge of OLAP, TFS and MDX has made this pretty daunting.

[image: SSMS Hierchy]

So, I can get this...

```
SELECT
[Measures].[Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_BaselineWork] ON COLUMNS,
[Work Item].[System_Id].MEMBERS ON ROWS
FROM [Team System]
WHERE [Work Item].[System_WorkItemType].&[WPS Task]
```

and this...

```
SELECT
[Measures].[Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_BaselineWork] ON COLUMNS,
[Work Item].[System_Title].MEMBERS ON ROWS
FROM [Team System]
WHERE [Work Item].[System_WorkItemType].&[WPS Task]
```

but combining the two has got me stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're after:

```
SELECT
[Measures].[Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_BaselineWork] ON COLUMNS,
[Work Item].[System_Title].MEMBERS * [Work Item].[System_Id].MEMBERS ON ROWS
FROM [Team System]
WHERE [Work Item].[System_WorkItemType].&[WPS Task]
```

The multiplication is a cross join between the System_Title and System_ID sets.  There is more information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144816.aspx)